# meteorjs WebApp.connectHandlers: how to match request params

Tags: web-applications, meteor, connect, middleware

i want to use [express like](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.params) request params.
but [`WebApp.connectHandlers`](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/webapp) do not match parameters like `/user/:name`.
should i use a middleware or something?

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried [Iron Router](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router)?

Here's an excerpt from their API:

```
Router.route('/items/:_id', function () {
  var item = Items.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
  this.render('ShowItem', {data: item});
});
```

Comment: actually, my previous implementation was based on Iron Router.
recently, i got this [open issue](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/971) and forced to use Meteor's webapp as a workaround

Comment: what do you need `.ready()` on the server for? are you waiting for a collection? you don't even need to think of subscriptions server-side..

Comment: I responded to that issue. It seems like your implementation was quite off. I'm about 90% sure you are configuring your routes in both client and server routes.